# Using MongooseJS to manipulate a single document/object

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, fs

I'm currently using JSON + fs to modify a single object while saving changes along the way in a JSON file.  I'm trying to understand how to do this in mongoosejs.  Here are the operations I'm trying to duplicate:

1. First we create/restore the object from the JSON file:

   `var file = fs.readFileSync('./file.json');`

   `var object = JSON.parse(file); //we can now treat this as a normal javascript object`
2. Now, after making changes to `object`, we can then save the changes whenever convenient:

   `fs.writeFile('./file.json', JSON.stringify(object));`

**Question:** What are the corresponding operations using *MongooseJS*?  I've read some of the documentation, but it doesn't seem that straightforward to me.  There is a lot of talk about schemas vs models vs documents, and it's not clear to me how to perform these two basic operations.

Comment: Mongoose is used to access BSON documents stored in a MongoDB database, so it's not meant to be used to manipulate JSON files.

Comment: I know; I'm looking for the analogous operations (i.e., I know no literal JSON is involved).  That is, I'm interested in finding out (i) how one creates/restores/saves a document from a mongo database using mongoose and (ii) how one converts it into a javascript object to manipulate and back.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. :)  Have you read through the ["Getting Started"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) guide for Mongoose?

Comment: I have, yes.  The answer to this question still evades me.  Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. :P